# What do "passes" mean in terms of gcc compilation?

Tags: gcc, compilation

I am working with compiler options like `fdisable-ipa-pass_name` or `fdump-rtl-pass`, but I could not find a explanation what these passes really are. What are passes and what is disabled in the first example and what will be dumped in the second example?

Answer (score 0):

Pass is a compiler module which performs a standalone transformation of compiled program e.g. unrolls loops or folds constants. Collection of compiler passes is called a compilation pipeline.